# RVM and Bundler, byebug gem: C extensions are not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rvm, bundler

I have been using Ruby on Rails with postgresql and something suggested that I should install RVM which I did (I think it was to utilise Phonegap). Since I put RVM in place I have been unable to execute `bundle install` which in turn means that I can no longer run other rails commands.

Lots of reading hasn't really given me an answer but I have lots of ideas. Maybe someone can help focus those ideas into a solution?

When I run `bundle install` there are 3 gems that seem to be causing the problem, but I think they are interlinked. They are `byebug 8.2.2` and `pg 0.18.4` and `binding_of caller 0.7.2`

The contents of `byebug-8.2.2/gem_make_out` are as follows:

```
/home/damo/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/bin/jruby -r ./siteconf20160927-16151-j7mhkf.rb extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
<top> at /home/damo/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:937
(root) at /home/damo/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
<top> at extconf.rb:6
extconf failed, exit code 1
```

When I look at [byebug issues](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/179) it simply says that byebug doesn't support jruby.

I did not have any issues before I installed RVM and I'm sure I read that byebug was hardwired into Rails 4. I wanted to tell you my Rails version but `rails -v` gives me a response of

```
Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.5) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Which seems to be my Catch 22!

Comment: OK, all is working now. Based on the responses below I assume that installing RVM switched me to default of jRuby. After I set `rvm use ruby-2.3.0` and reinstalled `bundler` I was then able to `bundle install` and repair things. To ensure I don't end up in a similar problem I ran `rvm default runy-2.3.0`. As an aside I have had to `chmod` some directories to grant me read/write access for installing gems.

Comment: To change the default ruby the correct instruction is `rvm --default use <NUMBER>`. After rebooting I still had a little problem with `gem install pg -v '0.18.4`. I don't know why but I needed to `sudo yum install postgresql-devel` which I would have expected to be need to use before now. Anyway, now all seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

This kinda sounds like you're not using RVM in a login shell. In Bash you can run `bash -l`, then `source ~/.bashrc` (or whatever contains your rvm invocation lines). After that, try `rvm use ruby-2.2` (or whatever), and if you don't get "RVM is not a function" error, then you should be good to go.

Note that under RVM you'll probably have to do `gem install bundler` manually for each distinct ruby version (and gemset), because ruby (and gemsets) under RVM live in their own worlds, and system `bundler` tends to be old. If you're reusing ruby installations and either not using or sharing gemsets, `bundler` may already be up to date.

So: use a login shell, do `rvm use <your_favorite_ruby_version>`, install `bundler` if necessary, then `bundle install`.

Last but not least, I like to use .ruby-version files so I don't have to switch rubies and gemsets manually, and I can tell if everything's working from the output of `rvm info`.

Comment: I recall issues with setting up RVM and I did pass the `RVM is a function` test before I proceeded. I have some further work to do based on @Doon answer but I think between you both I might get some joy. But I have thought that before ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Where you using jruby before you installed rvm?   Seems like your default ruby changed to jruby as opposed to whatever you where using before (system ruby?).

Try running

```
 rvm use system
```

in the root  of your rails project then try the bundle install and see if that fixes it. If it does then then can use setup .ruby-version files to control which version of ruby you use per project.

Or else type

```
  rvm use system --default
```

to set your default ruby back to the system one and continue like you where preciously.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was not using jruby, at least not to my knowledge. 
When I run `rvm use system` bash tells me that `Warning: PATH is not properly set up, '/home/damo/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0/bin' is not at first place,  usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...'` This seems like it might be linked to @eric answer above. I will have a play around and see what I can do.

Comment: I bet your rvm setup lines are in the wrong place (e.g. `.bashrc` vs `.bash_profile`).